# Expectation of the square of the minimum of iid positive random variables

Tags: probability, measure-theory, random-variables

Let $X_1, X_2$ be i.i.d., positive random variables with $E[X_i] < \infty$ (but $E[X_i^2]$ might be $\infty$). $Y := \min \lbrace X_1, X_2 \rbrace$. I want to show that $E[Y^2] < \infty$. The problem I face is that $X_i$ don't need to have a density function (otherwise this is trivial)

I tried approximations of the form $Y_n(\omega) = \min \lbrace q \in \frac{1}{n} \mathbb{N} \mid q > Y(w) \rbrace$, but this gives approximations like $E[Y^2] \leq C + \sum_{q \in \frac{1}{n} \mathbb{N}} \frac{2 E[X_1]^2}{qn} = \infty$ (using Markov's inequality, $P(Y \geq a) \leq \frac{E[X_i]^2}{a^2}$). I also tried splitting up $\Omega$ in $\int_\Omega Y dP$ into $Y < a$ and $Y \geq a$ but this again leads to nothing.

Markov's inequality alone is just a little bit too "weak". This problem looks so simple and I feel like I am missing something very simple here, a simple hint would probably suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, $E(Y^2)$ is finite, since $Y^2\leqslant X_1X_2$.

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't see it. $E(Y^2) \leq E(X_1 X_2)$ doesn't help (I only see this leading to some kind of Cauchy-Schwarz application) and I don't see any other application of this

Comment: ...And $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent hence $E(X_1X_2)=$ $_____$.

Comment: oh wow. bloody hell. I just wasted 10+ hours overthinking this.